# How to specify %digit values

Tags: batch-file, digit

I know nothing about bat files and I just received a batch file from a vendor that wants me to replace the values and run the batch.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM %1 is the name of the machine and SQL instance
REM %2 is the name of the database
REM %3 is the name of the machine 2
```

I know the names, but I do not know how to tell the bat file what they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not supposed to *replace* anything. Those `REM` lines are just telling you, what parameters are expected.
When the name of the machine and SQL instance is something like `Server1-inst05`, the name of the database is `VendorsBase` and the name of the machine 2 is `Workstation`, you should execute the batchfile (let's call it `vendor.bat`) like this:

```
vendor.bat Server1-inst05 VendorsBase Workstation
```

`vendor.bat` internally references those three parameters as `%1`, `%2` and `%3`

(that's the very same information given by npocmaka and BNT; just less technical)

Answer (score 2):

Update: after the edits and comments i think you are looking for [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19455611/7926064).

Its hard to help without the actual code but i assume that what you posted are comments of what the parameter values are.

So you would call the batch file and provide the values [as arguments](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) like

```
theScript.bat "name of machine and sql instance" "database name" "second machine"
```

The script itself would then evaluate the parameters as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26702/7926064)

Comment: So I don't have to do something like: 
Set %1="name of the machine" ???

Comment: when you are calling their script from the commandline or via e.g. start you dont have to set the variables but pass them as command line arguments

Answer (score 2):

`%1 %2 %3` are batch file arguments. To set values for them you can create another single line batch file that will call the first want with the arguments you want:

```
@call database.bat machine database_name machine2
```